# React how to remove listners correctly in componentWillUnmount, why do I need the bind in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm a bit confused, what is the difference between this sintax:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openPane: false
    }
    this.togglePaneHelper = this.togglePaneHelper.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.togglePaneHelper);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.togglePaneHelper);
  }
```

and this one:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openPane: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.togglePaneHelper.bind(this));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.togglePaneHelper);
  }
```

My concern is that the second syntax isn't removing correctly the listner and it cause this warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:**

```
a.bind(this) !== a.bind(this)
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The **bind()** method **creates a new function** that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Your first approach overrides `this.togglePaneHelper` with new, bound function. Second one removes different event listener function than it was added - both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` have to get the same **reference** of function.

Comment: So the first approach is the one that correctly removes the event listener? Any comment on this article: https://gist.github.com/Restuta/e400a555ba24daa396cc ?

Comment: Yes, first approach works as intended - same as it is discussed in that gist.